# Unable to update column in mysql

Tags: mysql, c

I tried to update my table in mysql using c.
I used the following code

```
if(row[6] == 0) // 6th column contains an integer 
{
mysql_query(con,"UPDATE users SET email_active = 1 WHERE user_id = 1");
}
```

But it's not working.

The main problem is with the comparison inside 'if' statement.

When I try to print the value of `row[6]`

```
printf("%d", row[6]);
```

It says

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]|

So when I try `%s` it works.

So I tried `if(strcmp(row[6],'0')==0)` but it shows a warning similar to the above warning.

Again I tried

```
if(row[6] == 0)
{
 printf("Works!");
}
```

It didn't print anything!

So, where I'm going wrong?

Also is there a way to use variable in `WHERE user_id = 1` instead of 1?

Comment: If you want to use a variable instead of hardcoding `WHERE user_id = 1` then you will have to use parameterized statements.  Please have a look at the [example in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html).

Comment: if(strcmp(row[6],'0')==0) <--- you should replace '0' with "0"

Comment: Thanks but can you please answer ---
What is the difference between using parameterized statements and using string concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "row" is an array of strings. Would you like to compare one of this entrys, use "strcmp".
if(strcmp(row[6], "0") == 0)

Comment: Thanks but can you please answer --- What is the difference between using parameterized statements and using string concatenation?

Comment: The use of string concatenation is potentially dangerous. In this case, you have to escape all data in the query. See the function _mysql_real_escape_string_ ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html)).

Comment: In the case of using _parametrized statements_, you can define an statement with placeholders for data to insert, update or in _where clauses_. For this placeholders, you can bind variables to the statement and if you execute the statement the _mysql client lib_ do all the rest for you.
I like this second case. ;-)
And sorry for the late answer. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, I got an idea.

> Using `strcat()` intead of parameterized statements.

At first I initialised a string `char update[100]="UPDATE users SET email_active = 1 WHERE user_id = ";`

And then for user's input

```
char temp[20];
gets(temp);
strcat(update , temp);
mysql_query(con,update);
```

And it worked!